# Prestashop NginX product images not displayed

Tags: nginx, prestashop, nginx-config, prestashop-1.7

I have eshop with version 1.7.6.2 and its running on NginX. There is some problem with display image of product in eshop. I think that there is some problem with NginX. When I upload image to product and I check in ftp images are ok but on eshop link on product return 404. But older images are  displayed. I think it's because they have a smaller id.

Maybe is some wrong in Rewritte Rulle.

Nginx version: 1.18.0

there is my config:

```
server {   #Use this to enable IPv6
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/mydomain/mydomain/www;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    client_max_body_size 25M;
    index index.php index.html;

    location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }   

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_types application/json text/css application/javascript;

    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+).(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
    rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;
    location /admin-dev/ {                           #Change this to your admin folder
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /admin-dev/index.php last; #Change this to your admin folder
        }
    }
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php last;
        }
    }

    location /admin054qrbqom/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /admin054qrbqom/index.php?$args;
     }

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60m;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 60m;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Did you follow this link? https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/basics/installation/nginx/